# maven: using snapshot version before given timestamp

Tags: java, maven

Assume that you are debugging the snapshot version of a product that was built 2 weeks back . So you have to build a version of a maven project A that is also 2 weeks old. And this module depends on snapshot versions of another maven project B that has had some interface changes in this 2 weeks time. So now Project A does not compile due to the interface changes in project B.

Question is how to force maven to use snapshot dependencies that is older than given timestamp (2 weeks or earlier in the example)?

**Update:**
I can temporarily set the required version of project B.  Something like `<version>x.y.z-{timestamp}</version>` instead of `<version>x.y.z-SNAPSHOT</version>`. But its difficult to manage to when there are multiple dependencies and transitive dependecies.

Comment: This is why you never ever want to release something with a snapshot dependency.

Comment: @GyroGearless - Not released. Its all internal still.  New Product build is not available yet.  So i have to debug on the older versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a version with reproducible builds, use release versions, not SNAPSHOTs.

SNAPSHOTs are purely for development and they may break any time.